# Detect browser autoclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have some problems in implementing my jQuery plugin.
I need a plugin which shows me some element (popup) and hides it when i click out of bounds of this element.

I implemented this plugin. But I have problems with forms in popup. When I calculate coordinates of clicked element I use `pageX` and `pageY` properties.

But it is some interesting things when I try to submit form using <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. When I push <kbd>ENTER</kbd> browser triggered 'click' event on submit button, but `pageX` and `pageY` of this button is equal 0. In `event.target` I see my button.

When I click submit button myself - everything is OK.

Question: how can I detect who clicked this button? User or browser? (without any spikes like detecting enter key on input or so on)

Additional: as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/InviS/JWpbP/1/) events are different (when click on submit and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>). But difference is so small... I see only that 'detail' property is set to 0, when we submit form by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Detail property is amount of clicks on element for mouse event.

Is it only way to detect submission? Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe you should be using `.submit()` rather then `.click()`?

Comment: What are "spikes"? How can a browser click a button?

Answer (score 3):

If you're binding a click handler to a click event and later calling the click programmatically as well as from a user click and want to differentiate the two events in the handler, you can check for eventObject.originalEvent which is set in the user click but not the .click() call.

Example:

`$('#el').click(function(evt){ if(evt.originalEvent){ //user click } else { // .click() call } });`

Comment: Nice approach. I didn't know that. But in my situation it's not a decision ;(

Answer (score 2):

How about testing for `pageX == 0 AND pageY == 0`?

Or even better, assuming it is a form (it implies from your post), why not use `.submit()` rather then `.click()`?

Comment: This is a spike I think :) Is it confirmed information that browser click on button and set pageX and pageY equal 0? Is it browsers defaults?

Comment: @InviS nope, but this is [TIAS](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=TIAS) Territory. You should really work with `.submit()` though.

Comment: Close form on any submit event? or something like that?
>> why not use .submit() rather then .click()
 - Browser generates click() event... ((

Comment: @InviS Exactly. I mean, you are trying to target the click on the submit button, which in turn submits the form. So take the more general approach and check for the submission rather then the click.

Comment: Forms is not everywhere :) Really I can use submit() event for forms inside of popup. But 'click' event on submit form is really strange. Never heard about this.

Comment: Ok. I have popup which appears when I click on some button. And I have to hide it when user click anywhere outside of popup. I use approach of click coordinates: when I click on 'body' I catch event.pageX and event.pageY and calculate bounds of popup. If outside - I hide it.